# Creating Redis conf parameter in AWS Elasticache

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-elasticache

I am currently writing terraform code to deploy an AWS Elasticache, this instance should use a conf file (if we are using a normal redis instance, it should be stored in /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf)
I found that we can use something like:

```
resource "aws_elasticache_parameter_group" "redis_parameter_group" {
  name        = "cache-params"
  family      = "redis5.0"
  description = "custom Redis parameter group to use redis.conf"

  parameter {
    name  = "config-file"
    value = file("${path.module}/config/redis.conf")  # path to custom redis.conf file
  }
}
```

But when I run apply it says

> Could not find parameter with name: config-file

Comment: Can you share where in the documentation have you found it can be done?

Comment: I didn't find it in the documentation actually, it was suggested by chatgpt (I'm not sure if its the correct way)

Comment: The list of available parameters is here. You can't provide your own config file in this way https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/ParameterGroups.Redis.html.

Comment: So that means I should have each parameter configured this way :   parameter { name  = "activerehashing"    value = "yes" } ? i can't do it in a more "compact" way ?

Comment: What does compact mean? You can use `dynamic` and `for_each` but that seems to be a different question compared to the OP.